# Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I'm facing the issue while trying to iterate and add the dynamic data. Below is the exception faced:

```
Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.
```

Demo:https://plnkr.co/edit/vvY6Bg3uzVDSMwDh3EI6?p=preview

js code:

```
var list = [
            {id:'January',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
            {id:'Feb',min: 11, max:4, start:15,end:4},
            {id:'March',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
            {id:'APril',min: 5, max:20, start:55,end:10}
        ];

       angular.forEach(list, function (value, key) {
     // data.addRows([{"v":value.min}, {"v":value.max},{"v":value.start},{"v":value.end}]);       
     data.addRows([value.min,value.max,value.start,value.end]);
       });
```

Any inputs on how to resolve the above exception?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 5 columns and 4 values in each row?

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Instant');
data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Instant');
data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Beans');
data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Beans');

   var list = [
        {id:'January',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
        {id:'Feb',min: 11, max:4, start:15,end:4},
        {id:'March',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
        {id:'APril',min: 5, max:20, start:55,end:10}
    ];

   angular.forEach(list, function (value, key) {
        var weekData = {};
  // data.addRows([{"v":value.min}, {"v":value.max},{"v":value.start},{"v":value.end}]);       
 data.addRows([value.min,value.max,value.start,value.end]);
```

Do you need to add a `Topping` value to each row?

The format looks slightly different in [this `DataTable` example](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews#javascriptliteral) but it looks like the same principle applies.

**Edit**:

It's expecting an array of arrays. You're giving it a single array.  [Here's a forked version](https://plnkr.co/edit/znmzZkbkeHJl0FKUXKRK?p=preview) that works:

```
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Instant');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nescafe Beans');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Folgers Beans');

       var list = [
            {id:'January',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
            {id:'Feb',min: 11, max:4, start:15,end:4},
            {id:'March',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
            {id:'APril',min: 5, max:20, start:55,end:10}
        ];

        var allRows = [];

       angular.forEach(list, function (value, key) {
            var weekData = {};
            allRows.push([value.id,value.min,value.max,value.start,value.end]);
      // data.addRows([{"v":value.min}, {"v":value.max},{"v":value.start},{"v":value.end}]);       
       });
            data.addRows(allRows);
```

Comment: I tried as suggested above, but still facing errors and the chart is not showing up. Demo https://plnkr.co/edit/PqV2JtJABgrnivzaACwM?p=preview . Any inputs?

Comment: @nan Fixed it and added example to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an array of arrays to [`addRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addRows) so you can get rid of the forEach. You could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert the array of objects to an array of arrays.

It also appears that you have 5 columns but are passing in only 4 values.

The fixed code would be something like this:

```
var list = [
    {id:'January',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
    {id:'Feb',min: 11, max:4, start:15,end:4},
    {id:'March',min: 10, max:20, start:15,end:10},
    {id:'April',min: 5, max:20, start:55,end:10}
];

data.addRows(list.map(function(value) {
  return [value.id,value.min,value.max,value.start,value.end];
}));
```

Or

```
data.addRows(list.map(value => [value.id,value.min,value.max,value.start,value.end]));
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/QGlz4fQ81vpmhvxyt4kB?p=preview